# Dialog values with MvvmCross, ActionBarSherlock and DialogFragment

Tags: actionbarsherlock, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I have a bunch of different libraries trying to work together and I'm pretty close but there's just one issue.

I have created a class called `SherlockDialogFragment` inheriting from `SherlockFragment` (rather than using the `SherlockListFragment` - this is because of the issue with the keyboard that's covered [here](https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/issues/337)). Here is my code:

```
    public class SherlockDialogFragment : SherlockFragment
{
    public RootElement Root
    {
        get { return View.FindViewById<LinearDialogScrollView>(Android.Resource.Id.List).Root; }
        set { View.FindViewById<LinearDialogScrollView>(Android.Resource.Id.List).Root = value; }
    }

    public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        var ignored = base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        var layout = new LinearLayout(Activity) { Orientation = Orientation.Vertical };
        var scroll_view = new LinearDialogScrollView(Activity)
        {
            Id = Android.Resource.Id.List,
            LayoutParameters = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FillParent, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FillParent)
        };
        layout.AddView(scroll_view);
        return layout;
    }
}
```

I then do the regular thing of creating an eventsource class which inherits from this but also uses `IMvxEventSourceFragment`, then the actual fragment class (which I call `MvxSherlockDialogFragment`) which inherits the eventsource class, as well as `IMvxFragmentView`.

That all works fine (and indeed I've created a `SherlockDialogActivity` the same way and it's fine), however the one issue is when I use this fragment on a screen with tabs (i'm using a class I made similarly to above called `MvxSherlockFragmentActivity`). When switching to the tab with the dialog, the view appears fine, even with pre-populated data. **However the issue is** when I switch away from that fragment/tab, and then back to it, the dialog elements all have the same value.

In my particular example, it's a login page with a username and password. When I first go into the fragment, everything is fine. When I go out and back in, the password value is in both the username field and the password field.

I'm sure it's got something to do with the `SherlockDialogFragment` class - in the `SherlockDialogActivity` class I also have this bit:

```
        public override void OnContentChanged()
    {
        base.OnContentChanged();
        var list = FindViewById<LinearDialogScrollView>(Android.Resource.Id.List);

        if (list == null)
        {
            throw new RuntimeException("Your content must have a ViewGroup whose id attribute is Android.Resource.Id.List and is of type LinearDialogScrollView");
        }

        list.AddViews();
    }
```

However this doesn't work in a fragment because there's no `OnContentChanged` event. Also, another difference is that in the `SherlockDialogActivity`, the layout is being created *ONCE* in the `OnCreate` event - however in the `SherlockFragmentActivity` I've got it being created each time the fragment is viewed. I know that's probably not the best way, but I tried to do it in `OnCreate` and save it in a variable and then return that variable in `OnCreateView`, but android *didn't like that*...

Comment: How are those tabs created? TabHost? Maybe the Mvx built in way? How are you binding the dialog elements?

Comment: Sounds to me like maybe a bug in https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/blob/v3/CrossUI/CrossUI.Droid/Dialog/LinearDialogScrollView.cs or lower - maybe try adding some trace to it or to your elements to find out why it's flattening your dialog. There are some convertview changes from @csteeg that I haven't integrated yet.

Comment: The tabs are add via the `AddTab` abstract void. Bound via `CreateInlineBindingTarget`. Stuart - please let me know where I should be tracing - also, feel free to point me in the direction of the updated code for `LinearDialogScrollView` and I can give that a go. Love your work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I feel like an idiot. I was creating/binding on `OnViewCreated` - however I need to do all my binding in `OnStart` - I think I was following some (possibly old) sample code from Stuart.

Obviously for a regular activity I'm using `OnCreate` but this doesn't work on a fragment, because the view is not initialised there - it's initialised at `OnCreateView`.

So for future reference - do all binding in `OnStart`!